# Convert between address types?

Tags: address

Is there any way to convert between Byron-era addresses (ie "Ae2tdPwUPEZ5faoeL9oL2wHadcQo3mJLi68M4eep8wo45BFnk46sMkvCmM9" or "DdzFFzCqrhswh7xiYG8RE1TtcvWamhbExTXfsCYaF9PrGWHRLCwCsBH5JkeApUagvo4FZE3DJD3rn5hw8vaMBib2StKMJ77rJHt51jPt" and the Shelley type (ie "addr1vx7vlgvuupzvvls99penvatpm2c4j9ljscevzsnn3awk8ys6xynxk")?

Failing that, is there a way to use `Cardanosharp` to generate the Byron type from mnemonic (I know you can use `PurposeType.Byron`, but it produces "addr1"-prefixed addresses, and I want the old Daedalus/Yoroi version)?  Can I do it in `cardano-address`?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use cardano-address to generate Byron addresses, starting from a mnemonic phrase.

You can use this script for that:
https://gist.githubusercontent.com/cardano-apexpool/f37f333eea7f8aac9a76687a94a9cf51/raw/5a5e613e1e352074993682fba3031cc6a4c3806e/byron_wallet_from_mnemonic.sh

Comment: Please add an example, otherwise this answer isn't very helpful.

Comment: I added the script. You can use an existing 12 words recovery seed or generate a new one, just edit in the script that part.